Angular sentence-case pipe disrupt also existing camel cases?
I have the following texts:
"please take care of your task"
"please think about Philip's idea"
I send them both through the same pipe, which displays them in sentence case:
 {{ textToDisplay | translate | sentenceCase }}

The problem:
The first sentence works as excepted:
"Please take care of your task"
The second sentence does not work as expected - it also changes existing camel-case words to lower-case.
"Please think about philip's idea"
Is there any argument I can send to the pipe, or maybe other existing pipe, to solve this problem?

This is default angular pipe

@user5260143 is it from sentence case there is no default pipe like that

Seems like you are using this sentencePipe from the @nglrx/pipes library.
Its behavior will convert the first letter as upper case and the rest as lower case.
Instead, you should implement a custom pipe to convert the first letter to upper case only and keep the rest:
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({
  name: 'sentence_lize',
  standalone: true,
})
export class SentencelizePipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform(value: string | null): string {
    return (value && value.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + value.slice(1)) ?? '';
  }
}

Then, import the SentencelizePipe and use as below:
{{ textToDisplay | translate | sentence_lize }}

Demo @ StackBlitz

create a custom pipe. The built-in Angular pipes do not have an argument to preserve the case of camel-cased words.
something like this should help:
export class CustomSentenceCasePipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform(value: string): string {
    if (!value) return value;
    return value.replace(/\w\S*/g, function(txt) {
      return txt.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + txt.substr(1);
    });
  }

we are using a regular expression in this case that to match each word in the string and then transform the first character of each word to uppercase while leaving the rest of the word as is.
use it like this in your HTML:
{{ textToDisplay | translate | customSentenceCase }}

